# custom class list initialization

Tags: asp.net, listview, c#-4.0

I have this list view with books object in it  that has a button and when i click on the button i want to add that object to my custom class(book) list so i declare a list in my code behind page class:

```
public List<Book> booklist;
```

and i initialize it in page load method:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
           booklist = new List<Book>();
        }
    }
```

and add the item in my list view Do Command event method:

```
    protected void DoTheCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        string commandName = e.CommandName;
        ListViewItem selectedItem = e.Item;

        if (commandName == "Foo")
        {
            string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Book b = new Book()
            {
                BookId = int.Parse(commandArgs[0]),
                Name = commandArgs[1],
                Author = commandArgs[2],
                Price = int.Parse(commandArgs[3])
            };
            booklist.Add(b);
        }
    }
```

but i get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error where should i initialize my list in order to preserve my data in every postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution your list is destroyed after each request.
A better solution would be to store the list in session so that the list remains allocated between requests

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["MyList"] == null)
       Session["MyList"] = new List<Book>();
   booklist = (List<Book>) Session["MyList"];
}
```